# Display 2 decimal places for amount in repeater control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater, decimal

I am displaying an amount value in my repeater control `(<%#Eval ("totalamt"))` and would like it to be formatted to 2 decimal places. The value from the database is 2 decimal, however, the repeater is displaying 4 decimal palces.

```
<asp:Label Font-Size="X-Small" ID="lblTotalAmt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval ("totalamt") %>'></asp:Label>
```

How can I display this with 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<asp:Label Font-Size="X-Small" ID="lblTotalAmt" runat="server" Text='<%#string.Format("{0:n2}",Eval("totalamt")) %>'></asp:Label>
```